# Can I extend a string using StringBuilder?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

Quick question most likely very simple.

Basically, I need to change a string from obdurate to obliteration.  I'm aware of the methods that I can use with StringBuilder but I'm unable to insert anything after the initial string.  Is there anyway to add more characters?

my code is as follows

```
public class SimpleString {

public static void main (String [] args){

StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder ("obdurate");

s1.delete(2, 7);
s1.replace(2, 7, "lite");
s1.insert(8,15, "ration");   //the problem line.



System.out.println(s1);
```

Comment: The code here doesn't even *compile* (Java 7), so I can't imagine you bothered looking at the javadoc, which explains that the index must be < string.length() (for the actual insert() methods anyway)

Comment: please refer this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html ,the way you call the insert method is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use StringBuilder.[append(String str)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28java.lang.String%29)

```
s1.append("ration");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the append():

```
s1.append("ration");
```

Comment: Append doesn't exist with indexes.

Answer (score 1):

you can **try** the following:

```
public class SimpleString {

public static void main (String [] args){

StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder ("obdurate");

s1.delete(2, 7);
s1.replace(2, 7, "lite");
s1.append("ration");  

System.out.println(s1);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to change a string from **obdurate** to **obliteration**.

Make use of [`indexOf(str)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with `replace(stIndx, endIndx, replacement)` function:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("obdurate it is");
int stIndex = builder.indexOf("obdurate");
int endIndex = stIndex + "obdurate".length(); // Find the end of the replacing string
builder.replace(stIndex, endIndex, "obliteration");
```

> Is there anyway to add more characters?

use `strBuilder.append(String)` function, where `strBuilder` is an instance of `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

```
s1.delete(2, s1.length());
s1.append("literation");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   public static void main(String[] args){

        StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder ("obdurate");

        s1.delete(2, 7);
        s1.replace(2, 7, "lite");
        s1.append("ration");

        System.out.println(s1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanna insert a string into s1, the best way of doing it would be

```
for (int start = 0, start < 7; start ++) // assuming you wanna insert a string with length 7
    s1.append(" ")
// s1 = "obdurate      " then now you can insert a new string easily
// you can now insert in between (i guess by using insert, you don't just want the string to be added in the end)
s1.insert(3,10, "rationa"); // s1 = "obdrationaurate";
```